# VBA conditional cell selection

Tags: vba, excel

I was having a play around with excel 2007 VBA and was hoping to create a Macro that generates a random number, then outputs a string based on the number generated. For example,

```
Number     String 
 1          Athena 
 2          Belerephone 
 3          Castor 
 4          Dionysos
```

If the random number is 4, the output would be Dionysos, 1 would be Athena and so on.

Basically, I want the Macro to search through the "Number" column, find the cell that matches the randomly generated number, then output the string in the cell to its right.

I have a table of a similar nature in my Excel worksheet.

So far I have not had much success at doing this, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data in A1 thru B4, use:

**=VLOOKUP(RANDBETWEEN(1,4),A1:B4,2,FALSE)** or its VBA equivalent

**EDIT#1** :

With the upper bound of the table stored in cell **D3** :

**=VLOOKUP(RANDBETWEEN(1,D3),INDIRECT("A1:B" & D3),2,FALSE)**

Comment: In the randbetween function, can you make it take cell values instead? I'd like to expand the spreadsheet beyond a1:b4...

Comment: So you want to go lower than **4** ??

Comment: I'd like to go higher, but the upper bound would be indicated in cell, say, D3...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `application.worksheetfunction.vlookup` to perform a vlookup within your macro, and use the `1+Int(10 * Rnd())` function to return random numbers from 1 to 10 (and possibly 11, but statistically unlikely).